# Is there any alternative to hyperledger-composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

As mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4673#issuecomment-544282601) the Hyperledger Composer project is in deprecated status since 29th August 2019.

I'll ask consequently, if there exist an alternative?

Answer (score 5):

Under Hyperledger umbrella, we have many projects and tools

`hyperledger composer is a tool` and `hyperledger fabric is a project`

hyperledger composer could be used for demo purposes.

**So coming to your question**: it's not about alternative it's about what available

since the composer is deprecated you can go with a traditional way of creating smart contracts and install it to the peers and go on.

As of now, smart contracts can be developed in the following available languages

- golang
- NodeJS
- java

This is what @david_k is trying to convey

Comment: Hyperledger really didn't categorise composer very well. It isn't a tool, but a framework for developing a specific class of applications.

Comment: But without fabric it cannot do anything right? so it is a tool, a framework like fabric should be standalone and independent

Comment: Sorry, I would disagree with classifying composer as a tool. It's main objective was as a programming framework, but provided tools such as playground and editor extensions to make it easy to develop composer applications. Would you class Angular as a tool ?

Comment: The naming is depending on the context where you come from when you take hyperledger fabric context then it is a tool but if you consider just programming then it is not a tool

Comment: Is the Composer Language, to define assets in a model file (.cto), deprecated as well?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Composer recommended using the new programming models that are now available in Hyperledger Fabric. These programming models are not only available for Node.js but Java as well and the intention is to bring them to Go Lang in the future.

Comment: actually it doesn't answer the question

Comment: In that case your question is unclear. Hyperledger Composer provided a framework for developing applications. The new programming models in hyperleger fabric come from the same team that created hyperledger composer and make it easier to develop hyperledger fabric applications. The hyperledger Composer team recommends using these new programming models as the way forward

Comment: Since Hyperledger Composer is just a tool/framework, which finally sticks to Hyperledger Fabric only, I'm asking, if similar tool/framework exists for Fabric or even Sawtooth. Please fill free to elaborate the question precisely.

Comment: There is nothing similar to composer as far as I know. There are other options that provide something of what composer provided. For example the new programming models in hyperledger fabric 1.4. There is the IBM Blockchain platform extension for VSCode. Also there is convector in the hyperledger labs to name just a few. I cannot comment about sawtooth as I have no experience of it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning VSCode. As to me it is an alternative, because VSCode is also just a tool. Please add a note about VScode to your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

***The simple answer is*- There is no more a direct alternative Hyperledger Composer as of now.**

Hyperledger Composer was being used to create applications (smart contracts)/PoCs quickly on top of Hyperledger core framework providing a set of easy to use APIs.

**Developer now have to build applications with their preferred languages (Java/ Go / Node.js ) directly calling the Hyperledger APIs**.